# NotXContentException when creating ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch 5.1.2 (Solaris)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a ingest pipeline using below PUT request:

```
{
    "description": "ContentExtractor",
    "processors": [
        {
            "extractor": {
                "field": "contentData",
                "target_field": "content"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is resulting in following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "not_x_content_exception",
                "reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
            }
        ],
        "type": "not_x_content_exception",
        "reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I see below exception in ES logs:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.compressor(CompressorFactory.java:57) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.convertToMap(XContentHelper.java:65) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineStore.validatePipeline(PipelineStore.java:154) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineStore.put(PipelineStore.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
```

This problem happening when Elasticsearch is running in Solaris, same request works fine in case of Linux. What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending sending the request to elasticsearch ? Java API, curl ? If using curl, maybe you have different options / versions between your os. Are you using the same elasticsearch version on both server ?

Comment: I am using Postman client to send the request by setting the content type as application/json. Yes, I am using the same elasticsearch version in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same error message but (on different version of elasticsearch and)  when querying with erroneous

- data format (misinterpreted doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html : "request body" is expected as plain JSON -- it is not intended to explain HTTP request body)
- or using old syntax within path of URL (just after 'index' in the URL) :

  curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://host:port/index/**_mapping/_doc** -d "**mappings=**@mymapping.json"

Just remove the "mappings=" and trailing path!